# Is the shortcut clone caret next brace in pyharm?

Tags: pycharm

`red = my_values.get('red', [''][0]***(my cursor)*** or 0)
green = my_values.get('green', [''][0]***(I want to clone caret this line)*** or 0)
opacity = my_values.get('opacity', [''][0]***(I want to clone caret this line)*** or 0)`

I want to clone caret next lines ']'. (by using multiple cursor)

Is there any shortcut in pycharm?

Answer (score 1):

> Use the shortcut ctrl+shift+a
>   Type clone carat (select up/down)
>   Use the shortcut alt+enter to assign a shortcut

This will allow you to create your own shortcut